# Is this an aspect of "destructuring assignment" or something else?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For reasons that are probably not relevant, I was experimenting with some JavaScript in Node v10.16.0 and discovered an odd effect that I cannot explain. The test code:

```js
let propertyName='Property';
let propertyValue='Value';
console.log('Before');
console.dir(propertyName);
console.dir(propertyValue);

{bibble:993}[propertyName]=propertyValue;

console.log('After');
console.dir(propertyName);
console.dir(propertyValue);
```

produces the following output:

```
Before
'Property'
'Value'
After
'V'
'Value'
```

As you can see, the line `{bibble:993}[propertyName]=propertyValue;` changes the value of `propertyName` from `Property` to `V` (or whatever the first character of `propertyValue` is). Some brief experimentation shows that the values `bibble` and `993` appear to be entirely arbitrary (and can even be omitted: `{}[propertyName]=propertyValue` also produces the same effect).

If this is a "real" or "official" effect (as opposed to an unintended quirk or even a bug of Node), I don't know its name, which makes it difficult to search for. It's possible that it's related to ***destructuring assignment***, specifically [**Assignment without declaration**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration), although the behaviour I'm seeing doesn't seem to match what's described there. Interestingly, that section says:

> **Notes**: The parentheses `( ... )` around the assignment statement are required when using object literal destructuring assignment without a declaration.
>
> `{a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}` is not valid stand-alone syntax, as the `{a, b}` on the left-hand side is considered a block and not an object literal.
>
> However, `({a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2})` is valid, as is `const {a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}`
>
> Your `( ... )` expression needs to be preceded by a semicolon or it may be used to execute a function on the previous line.

and, sure enough, if I replace the "offending" line with either a const-declaration:

```js
const x = {bibble:993}[propertyName]=propertyValue;
```

or wrap the line in parentheses as the quoted section suggests:

```js
({bibble:993}[propertyName]=propertyValue);
```

the "corruption" doesn't happen:

```
...
After
'Property'
'Value'
```

(But replacing it with just `const {bibble:993}=...`, instead of `const x = ...` produces the error:

```
[stdin]:6
const {bibble:993}[propertyName]=propertyValue;
              ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected number
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:277:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:329:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([stdin]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at evalScript (internal/bootstrap/node.js:589:27)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (internal/bootstrap/node.js:323:15)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

which seems to make sense, as the *desctructuring assignment* syntax only includes property names, not their values).

*It's really only to satisfy my curiosity, but can anyone explain *why* the first form is altering the value of `propertyName`?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> {bibble:993}[propertyName]=propertyValue;
> ```

Is equivalent to:

```
{
    bubble:
        993
}

[propertyName]=propertyValue;
```

i.e.

1. Start of block
2. *label* "bubble"
3. number 993
4. end of block
5. restructuring the "array" `propertyValue` so `propertyValue[0]` is assigned (i.e. the first character in the string)

Comment: It's so obvious when someone points it out... I wasn't thinking of restructuring a string into characters.